# Concrete Type Output variables in pipelines invalid JObject

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

I am trying to pass an array from a powershell script I have to a template but I am getting the error:

```
##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'Template parameter JToken type is not valid. Expected 'Object'. Actual 'String'. Please see https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for usage details.'.
##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

This is the powershell:

```
param(
    [string][parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $keyVaultName,
    [string][parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $resourceGroupName
)

$keyVault = Get-AzKeyVault -Name $keyVaultName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

if ($null -ne $keyVault) {
    $keyVaultAccessPolicies = $keyVault.AccessPolicies
    $armAccessPolicies = @()

    if($keyVaultAccessPolicies) {
        foreach($keyVaultAccessPolicy in $keyVaultAccessPolicies) {
            $armAccessPolicy = [pscustomobject]@{
                tenantId = $keyVaultAccessPolicy.TenantId
                objectId = $keyVaultAccessPolicy.ObjectId
            }

            $armAccessPolicyPermissions = [pscustomobject]@{
                keys = $keyVaultAccessPolicy.PermissionsToKeys
                secrets = $keyVaultAccessPolicy.PermissionsToSecrets
                certificates = $keyVaultAccessPolicy.PermissionsToCertificates
                storage = $keyVaultAccessPolicy.PermissionsToStorage
            }

            $armAccessPolicy | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name permissions -Value $armAccessPolicyPermissions
            $armAccessPolicies += $armAccessPolicy
        }
    }
    
    $armAccessPoliciesParameter = [pscustomobject]@{
        list = $armAccessPolicies
    }

    $armAccessPoliciesParameter = $armAccessPoliciesParameter | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5 -Compress
    Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=Infra.KeyVault.AccessPolicies;]$armAccessPoliciesParameter")
}
```

The Pipeline YAML

```
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    displayName: 'Provision Key Vault'
    inputs:
      deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
      azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ parameters.azureSubscriptionName }}
      subscriptionId: ${{ parameters.azureSubscriptionId }}
      action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
      resourceGroupName: '$(Resource.Group.Name)'
      location: '$(Region)'
      templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
      csmFile: '$(Provisioning.Package.Name)/Templates/key-vault-deploy.json'
      deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
      overrideParameters: >-
        -name "$(KeyVault.Name)" 
        -fooBar $(Infra.KeyVault.AccessPolicies)
```

The ARM template

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "fooBar": {
      "defaultValue": { "list": [] },
      "type": "object"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
      "name": "[parameters('name')]",
      "location": "North Europe",
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
      "properties": {
        "accessPolicies": "[parameters('fooBar').list]",
        "enabledForDeployment": false,
        "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true,
        "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
        "enableRbacAuthorization": false,
        "sku": {
          "name": "Standard",
          "family": "A"
        },
        "enableSoftDelete": false,
        "networkAcls": {
          "defaultAction": "allow",
          "bypass": "AzureServices",
          "ipRules": [],
          "virtualNetworkRules": []
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you deploying the new Key Vault into the same subscription that contains the Key Vault you're obtaining access policy information from in the PowerShell script? If yes, I would  add a `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` to deploy the new Key Vault in the same script and avoid the additional YAML task. Otherwise you should check out https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/14021

Comment: You are trying to pass a string to a parameter that expects an object. You have asked almost the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67924225/pass-array-to-arm-template/67994176 and part of the answer I gave there also applies here: Pass the json string (base64 encoded) to a parameter with the string type and use ARM template functions (`base64tojson()`) to convert the string to a json datatype within the template.