# Pass array to ARM Template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

I am trying to pass an array from an AzurePowerShell task to an ARM template but I am not sure how to do this.

I get the error:

- Not valid json when I attempt to pass it as a string and then use json function in ARM although when I print the json out and lint it, it is valid json.
- Can't convert string to object when the template expects an object.

Any help is appreciated.

I have a powershell script that grabs the access policies from my key vault:

```
$keyVault = Get-AzKeyVault -Name $keyVaultName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$keyVaultAccessPolicies = $keyVault.AccessPolicies
$json = $keyVaultAccessPolicies | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SAUCE;isOutput=true;]$json"
```

**EDIT**
I can see the value when debugging to be an array as its surrounded by square brackets. However, when outputted in pipelines the square bracket is omitted out. I find this strange and don't understand why its doing that.

However, how do I now pass this to a template?

```
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    displayName: 'Provision Key Vault'
    inputs:
      deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
      azureResourceManagerConnection: ${{ parameters.azureSubscriptionName }}
      subscriptionId: ${{ parameters.azureSubscriptionId }}
      action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
      resourceGroupName: '$(Resource.Group.Name)'
      location: '$(Region)'
      templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
      csmFile: '$(Provisioning.Package.Name)/Templates/key-vault-deploy.json'
      deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
      overrideParameters: >-
        -name "$(KeyVault.Name)" 
        -foo "$env:accesspolicyreference_SAUCE"
```

The is the key vault template

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "fooBar": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
      "name": "[parameters('name')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
      "properties": {
        "accessPolicies": "[json(parameters('fooBar'))]",
        "enabledForDeployment": false,
        "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true,
        "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
        "enableRbacAuthorization": false,
        "tenantId": "[parameters('tenant')]",
        "sku": {
          "name": "Standard",
          "family": "A"
        },
        "enableSoftDelete": false,
        "networkAcls": {
          "defaultAction": "allow",
          "bypass": "AzureServices",
          "ipRules": [],
          "virtualNetworkRules": []
        }
      },
      "tags": "[variables('tags')]",
      "dependsOn": []
      }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here:

1. Overriding an arm template parameter with a json string can get you into trouble, if it is not escaped correctly. I suggest, you encode the json as a base64 string:

```
$keyVault = Get-AzKeyVault -Name 'vaultbyenar2htogee'
$keyVaultAccessPolicies = $keyVault.AccessPolicies
$json = $keyVaultAccessPolicies | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
$sauce64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($json))
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SAUCE]$sauce64"
```

There is an arm template function [base64ToJson()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string?tabs=json#base64tojson) that directly decodes base64 encoded json strings into objects:

```yaml
 "variables": {
      "fooBar": "[base64ToJson(parameters('fooBar'))]"
  }
```

2. The object that you get from `$keyVault.AccessPolicies` is not a valid value for the [accessPolicies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults?tabs=json) property in the arm template. In order to make it work, you need to map the values into the correct structure with a [copy-loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources?tabs=json):

```yaml
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "fooBar": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
      "fooBar": "[base64ToJson(parameters('fooBar'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
      "name": "[parameters('name')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
      "properties": {
        "copy": [ {
            "name": "accessPolicies",
            "count": "[length(variables('fooBar'))]",
            "input": {
              "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
              "objectId": "[variables('fooBar')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].ObjectId]",
              "permissions": {
                "keys": "[variables('fooBar')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].PermissionsToKeys]",
                "secrets": "[variables('fooBar')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].PermissionsToSecrets]",
                "certificates": "[variables('fooBar')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].PermissionsToCertificates]"
              }
            }
          }],
        "enabledForDeployment": false,
        "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true,
        "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
        "enableRbacAuthorization": false,
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantid]",
        "sku": {
          "name": "Standard",
          "family": "A"
        },
        "enableSoftDelete": false,
        "networkAcls": {
          "defaultAction": "allow",
          "bypass": "AzureServices",
          "ipRules": [],
          "virtualNetworkRules": []
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": []
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

3. No need to use `;isOutput=true` if you will use the pipeline variable in a downstream task within the same job. (Otherwise you need to prefix the variable with the name of the task in which it was set, like: `$(myTask.SAUCE)`).