# Error while passing array from powershell script output to arm template as override parameter?

Tags: azure, powershell, templates

So I have a powershell script that returns an array of objects type of public ip name and publicip adress like follows:

```
[{"name":"pip-1","Address":"1.2.3.4"},{"name":"pip2","Address":"5.6.7.8"},{"name":"pip-3","Address":"6.5.4.3"}]
```

I set this variable array to use is arm template later like this:

```
$jsonresult = $ipObj| ConvertTo-Json -Compress


Write-Host $jsonresult 

Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=FirewallRules;isOutput=true]$jsonresult "
```

Then In arm template I pass this variable in the override section:

```
overrideParameters: > -FirewallRules"$(FirewallRules)"
```

Then inside template I set this parameter of firewallrules:

```
"firewallRules": {
      "type": "array",
    },
```

but then in pipeline I+m getting error:

```
The provided value for the template parameter 'firewallRules' is not valid. Expected a value of type 'Array', but received a value of type 'String'
```

I tried to encode this as it was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67924225/pass-array-to-arm-template):

this person also saying:  "Overriding an arm template parameter with a json string can get you into trouble, if it is not escaped correctly"

so is there a way to format the output someway that I don´t have this error? I need to fill in that parameter dinamically with output of the powershell script.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the issue is the incorrect input data format. You can run the code below and ensure that the $ipObj variable will be an array and the $jsonresult variable will be a string.

```
$ipObj = @(
    @{
        "name" = "pip-1"
        "Address" = "1.2.3.4"
    },
    @{
        "name" = "pip2"
        "Address" = "5.6.7.8"
    },
    @{
        "name" = "pip-3"
        "Address" = "6.5.4.3"
    }
)
$jsonresult = $ipObj | ConvertTo-Json

$ipObj.GetType()
$jsonresult.GetType()
```

Comment: yes good catch, but still if I add that tyoe of object like I´m doing now and you suggested:
Public IPs and IP Prefixes to add in Template: @{PublicIpName=pip-1; IpAddress=1.2.3.4} @{PublicIpName=pip2; IpAddress=5.6.7.8} @{PublicIpName=pip-33; IpAddress=6.5.4.3} }

Still getting same error. Is there another thing to consider to pass parameters to Arm templates?